# How can I add the same object to a ManyToMany field?

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

I need help on how to save the same (reference to an) object into a ManyToManyField.
For example I have models like this:

```
class Material(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Compound(models.Model):
    materials = models.ManyToManyField(Material)
```

In this example, the `Compound` can be made of one or many different `Material`s, and it also could be made from the *same* `Material` twice (same `id` in `Material` model).

If I try to save through a `ModelForm`, the second `Material` is discarded because it has the same `id` as the first `Material`.

What is the best approach for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest doing this as per http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

```
class Material(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Compound(models.Model):
    materials = models.ManyToManyField(Material, through='CompoundMaterials')

class CompoundMaterials(models.Model)
    Material = models.ForeignKey(Material)
    Compound = models.ForeignKey(Compound)
    Quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

What am I doing here? Well, Django normally automatically generates an intermediary table for holding pairs of keys associating compounds to elements. In this case we're definiting it ourselves, but not only that, we're adding additional data to the relationship i.e. the quantity you speak of.

As an example usage, what you might do is this:

```
$ python manage.py shell
from project.app.models import *

oxygen = Material(name="oxygen")
hydrogen = Material(name="hydrogen")
water = Compound(name="water")

oxygen.save()
hydrogen.save()
water.save()

water_chemistry_oxygen = CompoundMaterials(Material=oxygen, Compound=Water, Quantity=1)
water_chemistry_hydrogen = CompoundMaterials(Material=hydrogen, Compound=Water, Quantity=2)

water_chemistry_oxygen.save()
water_chemistry_hydrogen.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `ManyToManyField` -
Create a new model (`MaterialOfCompound`, for example), which holds two `ForeignKey`s - one to a `Material` record and one to a `Compound` object.

Then, to find all materials a compound is made of, you could use:

```
[x.material for x in MaterialOfCompound.filter( compound = my_compound ) ]
```

or something similar.