# Django, m2m with same model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have following models in my django app:

**Product** model:

```
class Product(BaseModel):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128,verbose_name="Product title")
```

**Order** model:

```
class Order(BaseModel):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
```

I am not able to add multiple *same* products to an order.
For example, I have product called "Car", how can I add multiple Car objects to single Order?

Every Order may contain multiple Products (same or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use third table for that task, for example:

```
class OrderProduct(BaseModel):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

and then you can use intermediary table https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

```
class Order(BaseModel):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='OrderProduct')
```

Unlike normal many-to-many fields, you can’t use add, create, or assignment (i.e., `order.products.add(prod)`) to create relationships. You should manually create record in `through` table:

```
prod = Product.objects.get(uuid=product)
#order.products.add(prod)
q = product_quantity
order = order # order record must be created before

OrderProduct.objects.create(order=order, product=prod, quantity=q)
```

check this questions:

- [How can I add the same object to a ManyToMany field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652888/how-can-i-add-the-same-object-to-a-manytomany-field)
- [adding the same object twice to a ManyToManyField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417825/adding-the-same-object-twice-to-a-manytomanyfield)

Comment: How can I add products to order? Before this change I was using code:

        `for product in products:
            prod = Product.objects.get(uuid=product)
            order.products.add(prod)`

Answer (score 0):

The many to many relationship with foreign keys works backwards. You don't need a foreign key in your Order model. What you need is a foreign key in the Product model linking to Orders (Every product will have an order) :

```
class Product(BaseModel):
company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, blank=True)
order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
title = models.CharField(max_length=128,verbose_name="Product title")
```

Comment: But every order may contain multiple (different or not) products. With your code, it won't work.